# How to set an IP address from a specific state in the US?

Tags: configuration, anonymity, help, ip-address

Is it possible, and if so how, to set tor so that my entry and/or exit IP will be from a specific state in the US ? Idk like NY, FL, TX, CA...
I already know how to choose a specific country, but i'd like to know if i can choose the state as well !

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to specify the US state for an exit relay. This is mainly due to two reasons:

1. Translating IP addresses to geographic locations is difficult, and even just IP to country is complicated.
2. There might be very few exit relays in a small geographic region and this can cause you to use a small set of exits for all of your circuits, harming your anonymity.

Answer (score 0):

there is no built-in way for doing that :(

but! if you have a dataset mapping between IPs and States, you can modify your `geoip` and `geoip6` files to allow that!

Answer (score -1):

The IP address belongs to the company that provided you with tcp/ip. The cheat is to find an address in an address pool you know, and will be allowed to use their DNS the first time you use the net. Microsoft made a "technology" call DHCP and want you to register on the net so they can monitor what you do. They offer you "address lease" and the right to use the address for a "Time to live" - "TTL". DHCP is a funny and strange animal, and since DNS was locked down while Microsoft still tried to avoid using tcp/ip according to standards and conventions.  In old days, a loose wire could take the entire net down, and with leftovers from XNS ("Netbios") there are a number of "funny things" that can be used and abused with "leases". So try to hit the net with a valid IP address and don´t use your ISP´s DNS but from the pool you have borrowed an IP address from. Use a DNS that your ISP has in another state. I use this method in Saudi Arabia.